# Check the fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host

Tags: ssh, fingerprint

I have got the well-known warning message when trying to `ssh` into a server:

```
$ ssh whateverhost
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:10
ECDSA host key for ipofmyhost has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

And I know why because I changed the ip of such server. But if it weren't so, how could I check the fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host?

I have tried to do so by:

```
echo -n ipofthehost | sha256sum
```

But I don't get the same fingerprint. I also tried "hostname,ip" kind of like in [AWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services), but I didn't get any match.

If I delete the entrance from my known_hosts file and I try to `ssh` again, it succeeds and tells the following:

```
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

So to what is it applying the sha256sum to get the fingerprint and how I could check it?

Comment: Without a known good value you can't check it. You only write it down the first time you start the SSHd and the keys are generated, and check against that known good value.

Comment: I edited your question. This site accepts only questions about a professional business environment. Home networking questions are offtopic here, I tried to save your question with my edit. Currently there is a vote against your question to close that on this ground.

Comment: @user186340 It does seem to be true that "you only write it down the first time you start the SSHd". If you have access to the machine running SSHd you can do `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub` to get the fingerprint. I just did.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A public key fingerprint isn't the simple hash of an IP address string.

To retrieve a remote host public key you can use `ssh-keyscan <IP address>`, and then you can use the usual tools to extract its fingerprint (`ssh-keygen -lf <public_key_file>`).

Finally you can compare the current fingerprint in your `known_hosts` file with `ssh-keygen -l -F <domain_or_IP_address>`.

Comment: I'm confused why when connecting via SSH and forcing an ecdsa key for the first time (`ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms='ecdsa-sha2-nistp256' william@my.server`) it gives me a 43-digit alphanumeric fingerprint (`ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:sBKcTiQ5V.... etc.`) yet when I run `ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub` I get 32 character hex??

Comment: @WilliamTurrell This is occurring because your server must have an older (likely pre- openSSH 6.8) version of `ssh-keygen` (or your server-provider hasn't kept up with the times and still only provides md5 hashes instead of the new SHA256). There are workarounds listed here: http://superuser.com/questions/929566/

Answer (score 13):

**A bit more in detail**: Because the warning message refers to the fingerprint for the [ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) key sent by the remote host, we gather the info about the public (ECDSA) key of the host:

```
ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa <IP_address_or_hostname> ECDSA_file_to_compare
```

Then we can find out where in our *known_hosts* file that the public (ECDSA) key is:

```
ssh-keygen -l -F ipofhost
```

If we want to compare the fingerprints we have to put in the contents of our *known_hosts* file (just the entry related to this host). We can call it ecdsa_file_from_known_hosts and then compare them as follows:

```
ssh-keygen -lf ecdsa_file_to_compare
ssh-keygen -lf ecdsa_file_from_known_hosts
```

And check if they show the same hash.

Of course they don't match, and that is why I got the warning message (`ssh` checks this matching internally). If we are sure about the IP address change (so we are not suffering a man-in-the-middle attack) we can just delete the entry of that host in our *known_hosts* file and the next time we `ssh` into it, a new fresh entry for it will be added to such a file.