# Digital Ocean server SSH login fault

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, digital-ocean

**What I have done**

1. created a new digital ocean droplet and
2. Created SSH key based on [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-ssh-keys-776639788.html) guide and during the creation of the droplet I have copied it in
3. I have run the following codes from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-18-04)

```
ssh root@your_server_ip
adduser sammy
usermod -aG sudo sammy
```

3. Than I have tried to log in as "sammy"

```
ssh sammy@your_server_ip
```

**ERROR**

- `Permission denied (publickey).`
- If I log in with root access than there is no problem I get in like before

**Fixes I have tried**

1. cleaned put the shh key folder and only have this key there
2. I haven't found any answer but my problem is kind of like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ssh-permission-denied-publickey)
3. this is not that similar to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/690855/check-the-fingerprint-for-the-ecdsa-key-sent-by-the-remote-host).
4. `ssh -vvv root@my_ip` from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ssh-permission-denied-publickey) it pushes out like lines of debug what should I look for?
5. I have tried to read sshd server logs on ubuntu [this](https://serverfault.com/a/480433/535406) most common messages

```
Disconnected from invalid user somefirstname43
Disconnected from invalid user someotherfirstname334
Disconnected from authenticating user root
Received disconnect from ID port ...
Accepted publickey for root from ID
Did not receive identification string from  ID port ....
Connection closed by authenticating user sammy ID port portnumber  <<----
```

Comment: You didn't add your public key to the user `sammy`.

Comment: how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an answer for this on [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ssh-copy-id-not-working-permission-denied-publickey)

1.Log in as root
`ssh root@IP`

2.Edit ssh config:
`sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

3.Change this line:
`PasswordAuthentication no`
to
`PasswordAuthentication yes`

4.Restart daemon:
`sudo systemctl restart sshd`

5.Do ssh-copy-id:
`ssh-copy-id someuser@IP`
(if you already have a key there it may not allow you to copy so just skip this step and log in with the next step)

6.Log in as the new superuser you  have created before `ssh someuser@IP`

7.Revert changes to ssh_config if you are security conscious and restart daemon.

Comment: trashing the sshd config just to avoid a mkdir and getting a chown+chmod right?  if these things scare you, you shouldn't be administering anything.  seriously, it's easy to set up ~user/.ssh/authorized_keys.  just chown -R user.user and chmod -R go-rwx .ssh

Answer (score 2):

Your user sammy needs the public key you used to login to the root user. The easiest way is to copy the authorized_keys file from your root user.

```
mkdir ~sammy/.ssh
chmod 640 ~sammy/.ssh
cp ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ~sammy/.ssh/
chown -R sammy:sammy ~sammy/.ssh/
```

Comment: Question when you say ```authorized_keys``` I just type that or where is the authorized_keys ?

Comment: `authorized_keys` is the file where the authorized public keys are stored. It is located in the `.ssh` directory in the users home directory. Theoretically you should be able to run the commands via copy&paste (as root).

Comment: I have typed in everything that you said only replacing "sammy" with my actual user name. I double checked, but when I try to log in with the other user still get ```Permission denied (publickey).```

Comment: then it's time to read the sshd server logs for actual error messages.

Comment: by the way I have only added the public key to my droplet during configuration. And than I only have done the commands that I show in my description

Comment: I have tried ```ssh -vvv root@my_ip``` from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ssh-permission-denied-publickey) it pushes out like lines of debug what should I look for?

Comment: Read the error logs on your server. Your client can't tell you what's the problem because it doesn't know.

Comment: How can I do that, like [this](https://serverfault.com/a/480433/535406)?